# CodeIgniter calling controller function from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, codeigniter, controller

Controller function

```
 public function remove_alarm() {
        $ida = $this->input->post('ida');
        $this->db->where('id_tracking_vehicle',$ida);
        $this->db->limit(1,0);
        $this->db->delete('tracking_vehicles');
        return ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
```

jquery call

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.remove_alarm').on('click', function() {
        console.log("remove");
        var ida = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'tracking/remove_alarm',
            data:{'ida':ida},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(ida);
                console.log('passed');
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

on click function works but it seems that i am doing something wrong with calling the function in CI controller (tracking) and passing the id variable ..

any advice or comments

Comment: try `'<?php echo base_url()."/tracking/remove_alarm";?>'`

Comment: what is (not) happening?

Comment: Your php function isn't sending anything in the response to your jQuery, you need to echo out some data for it to parse on return.
If you add `echo json_encode(array('ida' => $ida));` before return, then you should be able to pick it up in your jQuery in the success function using `data[ida]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full url instead of controller/action

Like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.remove_alarm').on('click', function() {
        console.log("remove");
        var ida = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>/tracking/remove_alarm',
            data:{'ida':ida},
            success:function(data){
                console.log(ida);
                console.log('passed');
                //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are also logging the var ida to the console on success of the ajax call. Wouldnt you want to log data since data is the var being filled from your php script?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this-

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('ControllerName/methodName');?>"
```

and in your method place following in starting

`echo 'called';
die;`